# HTML assistance.

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out why my to submit button takes me nowhere.  I am very new to HTML and programming.  Is anyone able to comb through and help me identify why this isn't submitting properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Place an Order - Love that Ink Pen Company</title>
    <script>
        // values
        var name = document.getElementById('cusName').value;
        var deliverydate = document.getElementById('delDate').value;
        var numItems = parseInt(document.getElementById('numItems').value); 

        // calculations
        var price = numItems * 4.25;
        var tax = price * 0.07;
        var shipping = price * 0.02;
        var totalCost = price + tax + shipping;

        // Output text
        var text = 'Thank you ' + name + 'for you order.<br/>';
        text += 'You will receive ' + numItems + ' items delivered to you on ' + deliveryDate + '.<br/>';
                text += 'You price of your items is $' + price.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
            text += 'The tax charge is $' + tax.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
                text += 'The shipping charge is $' + shipping.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
            text += 'Your total is $' + totalCost.toFixed(2) + '.<br\>';;

        // Results
        document.write('<h2>' + text + '</h2>');;
        } 
      </script>  
</head>
<body>

    <div style="text-align: left; background-color:Orange; color:Black; 16px;">
        <h1>Place an Order</h1>

      <form action="#"> 
         <label>Customer Name:</label>
             <input type="text" id="cusName"><br>

         <label>Delivery Date:</label>
         <input type="text" id="delDate"><br>

         <label>Number Items:</label>
         <input type="text" id="numItems"><br>
    </div>  

    <div style="text-align: left; background-color:Green; color:Black; 16px;">
         <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateTotal(); return false;" />
    </div>

    </form> 

    <div style="background-color:Orange; color:Black; 16px;">
        <h2>
            Visit our <a href="https://www.pens.com/" target="_blank">External Website</a>
        </h2>

        <h2>
            <a href="week1-1.html">Link</a> to our main page.
        </h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't just want an answer, I am looking for what I am doing wrong.  I want to learn and understand where I am not comprehending.

Comment: Where is your function `calculateTotal()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you are taking the form to submit the data for your
   application there will be no need to form you can do it without form
   as well as with form.
2. second thing is you are calling `calculateTotal()` function and you
   didn't made the function in script tag.
3. third thing is that `deliverydate` and `deliveryDate` are different
   thing that you have to change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Place an Order - Love that Ink Pen Company</title>
    <script>
        // values
        function calculateTotal(){
        var name = document.getElementById('cusName').value;
        var deliverydate = document.getElementById('delDate').value;
        var numItems = parseInt(document.getElementById('numItems').value); 

        // calculations
        var price = numItems * 4.25;
        var tax = price * 0.07;
        var shipping = price * 0.02;
        var totalCost = price + tax + shipping;

        // Output text
        var text = 'Thank you ' + name + 'for you order.<br/>';
        text += 'You will receive ' + numItems + ' items delivered to you on ' + deliverydate + '.<br/>';
                text += 'You price of your items is $' + price.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
            text += 'The tax charge is $' + tax.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
                text += 'The shipping charge is $' + shipping.toFixed(2) + '.<br/>';
            text += 'Your total is $' + totalCost.toFixed(2) + '.<br\>';;

        // Results
        document.write('<h2>' + text + '</h2>');;
        } 
      
      </script>  
</head>
<body>

    <div style="text-align: left; background-color:Orange; color:Black; 16px;">
        <h1>Place an Order</h1>
      
         <label>Customer Name:</label>
             <input type="text" id="cusName"><br>

         <label>Delivery Date:</label>
         <input type="text" id="delDate"><br>

         <label>Number Items:</label>
         <input type="text" id="numItems"><br>
    </div>  

    <div style="text-align: left; background-color:Green; color:Black; 16px;">
         <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateTotal(); return false;" />
    </div>

    

    <div style="background-color:Orange; color:Black; 16px;">
        <h2>
            Visit our <a href="https://www.pens.com/" target="_blank">External Website</a>
        </h2>

        <h2>
            <a href="week1-1.html">Link</a> to our main page.
        </h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You I really appreciate your help.  This is for an assignment and I am required to use a form.  I kept the form action and changed the calculateTotal to be within the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for what I am doing wrong.

1. You have defined the script tag in header section ,DOM is not ready when `document.getElementById` will be executed.Remove them to closing end of body tag

   `<body>
        <!--html-->
       <script>
         //js code
       </script>
     </body>`

or use `windows.load`

2.There is no function defined `calculateTotal`

3.There is an extra colon (:) and `}` here

`document.write('<h2>' + text + '</h2>');;}`

4.Typo at `deliverydate`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your assistance.  I changed the deliverydate typo and changed the the document.write error.